run js after shopify collection page sort/filter
i am using js to alter each item's info after the page loads.  however, when a collection is sorted and the items are reloaded the effect is removed.  the sort function is not included in the API and mutation observer isn't working.  how can i detect when the sort/filter function is complete and the items are done reloading?  thanks!
